# how do I get objects by values whose property size is not up to a particular number or is empty or null in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have a mongoose schema with a property of `bvn`, `bvn` values have a length of 11 by default, I want to query the schema to get the objects that have bad `bvn's`, this includes

1. `bvn's` with null.
2. `bvn's` empty string
3. `bvn's` values less than or greater than 11.

I tried achieving this by using the following line:

```
await this.find({
      'bvn': { '$exists': true },
      '$expr': { 'ne': [ { '$strLenCP': '$bvn' }, 11 ] }
    }).exec()
```

but got the error:

> MongoError: $strLenCP requires a string argument, found: null

how do I achieve getting bad `bvn's`, what am I doing wrong and can I achieve this with less code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a string that is not empty a valid value? If so this should work for you:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/dJ2FMc8JWB4

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {bvn: {$exists: false}},
    {bvn: ""},
    {bvn: {$gt: 11}},
    {bvn: {$lt: 11}},
  ]
});
```